# XML validation against another xml file

Tags: java, xml, validation

My application looks if all the attributes are on the XML and extracts the data to the TXT file. The only way that I can use to find out that an XML file does not have all the attributes is when I run the app on my production enviroment.

How can I verify the XML before I run my production app?

Comment: Why can't you write a standalone validation tool yourself?

Comment: How about running it in your development or testing environments?

Comment: you can write a standalone Java app to make the validation, if there's existing code you have a good model. If you face a problem, then you can come here and show your code (and XML sample file) and where are you having issues so people here can kindly help you :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your recomendations, i'll try to write the standalone application so i can validate the XML files.